# Generics vs. Inheritance

Tags: java, generics

I was messing around with some Java code in my terminal, when I came across the following problem. Let me preface it.

Check out the following code:

```
Integer x = new Integer(5);
Number y = x
```

Here, we are simply declaring an Integer object, and then creating a reference to it with the use of superclass Number. This works fine and dandy, because the Integer *is a* Number.

Thus, it would seem intuitive that the following code should work too:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>();
x.add(6);
ArrayList<Number> y;
y = x;
```

But this code gives us an error stating incompatible types: `ArrayList<Integer> cannot be converted to ArrayList<Number> y = x;`

Now I am confused. As I understood generics, I thought we were declaring an ArrayList `x` that is being enforced to hold only objects of the `Integer` class at both compile time and run time. And since `Integer` is a `Number`, then it makes sense that we should be able to treat all Integers as Numbers. But this thinking doesn't line up: What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Ooh, wait I just realized one reason why the compiler may not have liked this... with my line of thinking, we can now add ```Numbers``` to the ```Integer``` ArrayList during compile time.

Comment: Correct. You just identified that `ArrayList` is invariant and then figured out the chief problem that arises if we try to pretend that it's not invariant.